# How to use different base_url for http(test) and https(live) environments?

Tags: php, codeigniter, http, https, base-url

I'm continuing a codeigniter project which will be uploaded in the server. When it's in the local network (only accessible inside the network) we should use (e.g. http://test-svr) as our base_url but when we want to access it from outside the network, we should use the live version which is (e.g. https: //live-svr). This is now the content of our (globals.php)

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {   
       $url = 'https://';
       define('HOSTNAME', $url . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']);}

else {
       $url = 'http://';
       define('HOSTNAME', $url . 'test-svr');
}

define('APP_HOST', HOSTNAME . '/app/');
```

then on our (config.php) it will look like this

```
$config['base_url']   = APP_HOST;
```

PROBLEM:
Right now, the whole project is only working on (http: //test-svr) but won't load on (https: //live-svr).

And since my if-else case relies on $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] when I print that value it produces '80'.

As for not directing the changes on the config.php file, we've done the same thing (if-else case) but only got the same results.

Comment: i could not understand your problem. can u explain ?

Comment: The project will only run on the test (http) environment but not on the live (https) environment.

Comment: what you get when you put https ?

Comment: https vhost is correct implemented?

Comment: if I put the (https://live-svr) url directly on the base_url then the project will run only on the live(https) environment but not on the test(http) environment. It's a requirement that the project should run on both the test and the live environment.

Comment: Codeigniter allows you to use different config files depending on [environment](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/environments.html). And you can decide what environment to use in your .htaccess file.